# Unable to drag and drop in Selenium WebDriver using Robot

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, awt, awtrobot

I'm trying to automate drag and drop functionality using Robot framework. In order to achieve that I wrote following code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop");

WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.id("column-a"));
WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.id("column-b"));

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(source.getLocation().getX() + (source.getSize().getWidth()/2), source.getLocation().getY() + (source.getSize().getHeight()/2));
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
robot.mouseMove(target.getLocation().getX() + (target.getSize().getWidth()/2), target.getLocation().getY() + (target.getSize().getHeight()/2));
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Executing above code, I could see mouse is moving to both source and target but drag and drop isn't happening. Can you please let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You added the "robotframework" tag, but this appears to have nothing to do with the robot framework from robotframework.org.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this method  — to get the source, please embed this with your code:

```
  WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='column-a']"));
  Locatable element = (Locatable)source;
  Point p= element.getCoordinates().inViewPort();
  int sourceX=p.getX()+25;(25 can be increased or decreased accordingly) 
  int sourceY=p.getY()+120;(120 can be increased or decreased accordingly)
```

For the destination, please embed this with your code:

```
  WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.id("column-b"));         
  Locatable elementTarget = (Locatable)target;
  Point Target= elementTarget.getCoordinates().inViewPort();
  int targetX=Target.getX()+55;
  int targetY=Target.getY()+150;
```

Comment: Your solution might work here, but your code is using hard coded values which won't work if we place that code in a method and try to use that method for different tests.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with both JTable and JList.

For the table, I had to drag far enough with the table or it never becomes a Drag Gesture.

With a list, I not only needed to go far enough, but had to add a way point in the middle and pause there long enough for it to realize what was going on.  Otherwise, it tried to drop it there with a zero length DataFlavor array.

Ended up with Robot code like:

```
public void dragAndDrop(Point start, Point end) {
        // Press
        mouseMove(start.x, start.y);
        delay(100);
        mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        delay(500);
        // Drag - through a way point, so this will work on JLists - make sure you linger long enough at the way point too!
        mouseMove(start.x - (start.x - end.x)/2, start.y - (start.y - end.y)/2);
        delay(500);
        mouseMove(end.x, end.y);
        delay(1000); // So you can see what is happening
        mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        // Wait (copied from other code)
        waitForIdle();
        delay(200);
    }
```